# Showing the upper bound of the operator norm of a rectangular matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, upper-lower-bounds, random-matrices, matrix-norms

**Question:** Given a **square** random matrix $X\in\mathbb{R}^{p\times p}$ where
$$
X_{ij}\stackrel{iid}{\sim}\text{Bernoulli}(\alpha),
$$
where $\alpha\in(0,1)$, satisfies the condition
$$
\|X\|_{\text{op}}<C \text{ almost surely},
$$
where $\|X\|_{\text{op}}$ is the operator norm of the matrix (see definition 10.2 of this [note](http://www.njohnston.ca/ala_week10_annotated.pdf)) and $C$ is some constant. Can I use this result to show that for a **rectangular** matrix $\widetilde{X}\in\{0,1\}^{n\times p}$ where $n<p$, with entries generated in the same manner, the same condition $\|\widetilde{X}\|_{\text{op}}<C$ holds? Note that the only difference is that we shifted from a square matrix to a fat-rectangular matrix (with no other changes). Thanks.

**Attempt:** I can argue that the result also holds for $\widetilde{X}$ because we can always pad $\widetilde{X}$ with more i.i.d. samples to obtain a square matrix that satisfies the bound almost surely. However, I find my argument to be not very rigorous... Is there a more rigorous argument, or a way to make my argument more rigorous? Thanks.

Comment: I am assuming $n<p$. Sorry for the confusion, I have updated the question. Thanks.

Comment: If $n<p$, then you would pad it to a $p\times p$ matrix, but the original claim is for $n\times n$. That issue aside, I believe the main point here is can you pad a rectangular matrix, without changing the operator norm? If you just pad with $0$s, then I believe the operator norm must agree. Since the original condition holds surely, you get the desired conclusion

Comment: It is just any square matrix, thanks.

Comment: ok thank you very much.

Comment: @user1551 you mentioned that if $np\leq m^2$, then the answer is yes. Can you show me rigorously (step-by-step) why that is the case? You can add it as an answer to this question perhaps? Thanks.

Comment: **Note:** I have simplified the question by setting $m=p$.

Comment: My bad. I was thinking about something else and my conclusion was erred. Anyway, when $m=p$, the answer is yes, for a very simple reason. Note that the Bernoulli distribution has a finite sample space. Therefore, any event that occurs almost surely must occur always. The statement that “$\|X\|<C$ a.s.” is thus equivalent to $\max\limits_{X\in\{0,1\}^{p\times p}}\|X\|<C$. However, when $n<p$, we have $\max\limits_{Y\in\{0,1\}^{n\times p}}\|Y\|\le\max\limits_{X\in\{0,1\}^{p\times p}}\|X\|$ because $\|Y\|=\left\|\pmatrix{Y\\ 0}\right\|$. Hence the result follows.

Comment: Great, thank you!